# OpenCV/EmguCV Version 2 to OpenCV/EmguCV Version 3 conversion

Tags: emgucv

Granted I am learning OpenCV/EmguCV and actually prefer EmguCV as the wrapper is quite nice.

But, lots of the examples/tutorials found out on the web are for version 2.X and do not compile under version 3.0. Things like Contour is not supported in version 3. Is there a document/web site that anyone can point me to so I spend less time porting and more time actually learning and doing?

Comment: Are you looking for the [transition guide](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0)?

Comment: please do not use an opencv tag, if you're using emgu. the api's differ significantly, also, there's no support for this from opencv.

Comment: @berak, I am quite well aware of how different the APIs are. However, my reasoning was if there was a something to guide a 2.X to 3.0 OpenCV transition that perhaps I could extrapolate from the the EmguCV changes.

Comment: @Miki, Thanks! Yes that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just answered this question here: [Emgu CV 3 findContours and hierarchy parameter of type Vec4i equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120260/emgu-cv-3-findcontours-and-hierarchy-parameter-of-type-vec4i-equivalent/34751378#34751378)

As you mentioned, Contours are not correctly implemented in Emgu 3, but you can manually invoke the FindContours method and it will work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Find contours using the specific memory storage
/// </summary>
/// <param name="method">The type of approximation method</param>
/// <param name="type">The retrieval type</param>
/// <param name="stor">The storage used by the sequences</param>
/// <returns>
/// Contour if there is any;
/// null if no contour is found
/// </returns>
public static VectorOfVectorOfPoint FindContours(this Image<Gray, byte> image, ChainApproxMethod method = ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple,
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType type = RetrType.List) {
    //Check that all parameters are valid.
    VectorOfVectorOfPoint result = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

    if (method == Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainCode) {
        throw new ColsaNotImplementedException("Chain Code not implemented, sorry try again later");
    }

    CvInvoke.FindContours(image, result, null, type, method);
    return result;
}
```

And to use those contours:

```
    VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = canvass2.FindContours(ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple, RetrType.Tree);
    int contCount = contours.Size;
    for (int i = 0; i < contCount; i++) {
        using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i]) {
            segmentRectangles.Add(CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour));
            if (debug) {
                finalCopy.Draw(CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour), new Rgb(255, 0, 0), 5);
            }
        }
    }
```

I just went through the same conversion process, so I can answer a lot of the issues if you can be specific to what other problems you have had.

Comment: Chris,
Thank you! I appreciate the answer and the offer for some help.

Doug