# How to convert contour hierarchy from python openCV to emgu cv to find enclosing contours

Tags: python, c#, opencv, emgucv

I have a circle detection written in python which I now need to convert into emgu cv to enable bundling into an Xamarin IOS App.

For that I save images of the detection process at various parts to compare it to the new .net implementation. While some parts are straight forward others seems to be more tricky. I am currently stuck on the hierarchy for detected shapes and already checked for examples as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710876/701988) which I then picked as a first solution.

This is the python line I try to convert:

```
# finding all contours in the image which are enclosed within other contours (child contours)
( cnts, cnts_hs ) = cv2.findContours(img.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
cnts = [cnt for i,cnt in enumerate(cnts) if cnts_hs[0,i,3] != -1]
```

Currently I tried it using the mentioned answer which results in the following implementation:

```
// finding all contours in the image which are enclosed within other contours (child contours)
// NOTE: 
// 'hier' is of type 'Mat'
// 'cnts' 'cntsContourOut' are both of type 'VectorOfVectorOfPoint'
CvInvoke.FindContours(img.Clone(), cnts, hier, RetrType.Ccomp, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
int count = cnts.Size;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    using (VectorOfPoint cntr = cnts[i]) {
        // check if the contour is enclosed in another contour
        if (hier.GetDataPointer(i).ToInt32() != -1)
        {
            cntsContourOut.Push(cntr);
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is quite different... while the python lines results in 49 contours after filtering for a given sample-image the .net lines result in the original 91 contours (none is filtered out).
I guess I have some misunderstanding what the python line does, which I still have when it comes to the `0` or `3` in `cnts_hs[0,i,3]`. That's why I just left them out in the .net implementation.

### Edit 1:

I guess I should have mentioned that I tried the following param variants for `hier.GetDataPointer()`:

```
hier.GetDataPointer(0,i,3)
// result in an array size exceeded exception

hier.GetDataPointer(i,3) // or even 4 instead of 3
// result in the same 91 contours
```

Comment: In Python, `cnts_hs` is an array of shape `[1, #contours, 4]`. The first dimension is a singleton dimension, which is only needed for convenience when used in other OpenCV functions. The four values in the last dimension are explained in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). When using the exact implementation from the linked Q&A, i.e. `Get(HierarchyIndex component, int index)`, you most likely need `if (Get(i, 3) == -1)` (or `Get(i, 4)` if 1-based indices are used).

Comment: @HansHirse thanks for your comment. I must admit that the linked answer just led me to my current approach while having no clue of the detailed going on. `GetDataPointer(int[])` accept in array of integers which I already tried (I should have mentioned that from the start. I now added it to the Question as Edit 1). The `Get(HierarchyIndex component, int index)` described is not available or until now I didn't found it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging in I've found the solution:

```
var data = hier.GetData();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    using (VectorOfPoint cntr = cnts[i]) {
        var d = (int)data.GetValue(new int[3] { 0, i, 3 });
        if(d != -1)
            cntsContourOut.Push(cntr);
    }
}
```